# HTML Column Span for 2 Tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a table that is basically two tables in 1:

- A first top table with 3 sections
- A second bottom table with 5 sections
  (as in the pic attached, pardon my really bad paint skills)

[image: what I'm trying to accomplish]

I tried to do it but it's looking a bit funky (excel replicated pic attached)

[image: Result I'm getting right now]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just add 2 tables of the same width and set the top margin for the bottom one to 0 and the bottom margin for the top one as well?

Comment: Use colspan attribute in <td>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem is that the `colspan` is not dividing equally (it must be an integer and not a float) because `5` is not a multiplier of `3`. I advise trying to work with 2 separate tables.

```css
table{ 
  width:300px; 
  text-align:left; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  font:20px Arial; 
  resize: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table th{ font-size:1.2em; color:white; }
table th:nth-child(1){ background: LightSkyBlue; }
table th:nth-child(2){ background: MediumOrchid; }
table th:nth-child(3){ background: YellowGreen; }
table td{ border:1px solid silver; }

.header{
 background: LightSkyBlue;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan=2>1
      <th colspan=2>2
      <th colspan=2>3
  <thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=2>1
      <td colspan=2>2
      <td colspan=2>3
    </tr>
    <tr class='header'>
      <td colspan=5>secnod header
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1
      <td>2
      <td>3
      <td>4
      <td>5
    </tr>
  <thead>
</table>
```

---

You can also add a `<table>` inside a cell (`<td>`) of the "main" table:

```css
table{ 
  width:300px; 
  text-align:left; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  font:20px Arial; 
  resize: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table th{ font-size:1.2em; color:white; }
table th:nth-child(1){ background: LightSkyBlue; }
table th:nth-child(2){ background: MediumOrchid; }
table th:nth-child(3){ background: YellowGreen; }
table td{ border:1px solid silver; padding:0; }

table table{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  resize: none;
}

table table thead{ text-align: center; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1
      <th>2
      <th>3
  <thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1
      <td>2
      <td>3
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=3>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan=5>Header
          <thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1
              <td>2
              <td>3
              <td>4
              <td>5
            </tr>
          <thead>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <thead>
</table>
```

Comment: the header of the second table needs to occupy entire width

Comment: @ShivamSingh - ok, give me 10 seconds. That's very basic to do...

Comment: thank you! that's actually the most rational way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @JB999 - updated the answer with another alternative solution

Answer (score 1):

it's isnt good practice but you can add another  inside  element

```
 <tfoot>
<tr class='header'>
      <td colspan=5>secnod header
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1
      <td>2
      <td>3
      <td>4
      <td>5
    </tr> </tfoot>
```